# C pthread_join() generates Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

The below code gives seg fault for the second case but for the first part it is working fine . but both of them are doing the same thing . Here the pthread_join() call is not generating any error , but while printing the response from the pthread_join() it generates Segmentation fault . What the first one is doing is different from the second one ? and Where the second one is actually wrong ?

## Code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void * thread_ops(void *arg){
  printf("Thread Start!\n");
  int val=((int *)arg)[0];
  printf("value at thread -> %d\n",val);
  int * c=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int *));
  *c=val;
  pthread_exit((void*)c);
}
int main(){
  pthread_t pt,pt2;
  pthread_attr_t ptatr;
  int ar[1]={1};
  // working
  pthread_attr_init(&ptatr);
  int status;
  status=pthread_create(&pt,&ptatr,&thread_ops,ar);
  printf("Thread Stats : %d\n",status);
  int *result;
  pthread_join(pt,(void **)&result);
  printf("Result is %d\n",*result);
  // why does the next set of lines generate seg fault ??
  void **result2;
  status=pthread_create(&pt,&ptatr,&thread_ops,ar);
  pthread_join(pt,result2);
  int ** res2=(int **)result2;
  printf("Result is %d\n",**res2);
  return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Thread Stats : 0
Thread Start!
value at thread -> 1
Result is 1
Thread Start!
value at thread -> 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `result2` is a pointer pointer. Since it is unititialised, it points to garbage. When `pthread_join` tries to put the result to that  garbage adress, it fails. You had the correct way for `result` and the first join.

Comment: did you try to run it using valgrind?

Comment: @litelite what I understand from pthread_join () is that it takes the second parameter as void ** retval, and this stores the address of the pointer returned by pthread_exit(). So , ultimately some address is stored in the pointer to pointer result 2. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @litelite thanks go that ,  void **result2=(void **)malloc(sizeof(void **)); solves the issue , thanks a lot .

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`.  And it should be `int *c = malloc(sizeof(int))` - the size you pass to `malloc` is the size of the _thing pointed to_.

Comment: (If you are actually compiling this program as C++, then either stop doing that, or switch to `new` and `delete`.)

Comment: Why this cast `int val=((int *)arg)[0];`??

Comment: @alk to cast to int* from void * which is not done explicitly right ?

Comment: The cast is correct and necessary... - temp brain lapse on my side... pls excuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
void **result2;
pthread_join(pt,result2);
```

use

```
void *pvresult;
pthread_join(pt, &pvresult);
```

and as you expect an `int` add the following:

```
int result = *((int*) pvresult);
```

and print it this way:

```
printf("Result is %d\n", result);
```

---

Also replace this

```
int * c=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

by this

```
int *c = malloc(sizeof *c);
```

Comment: threading.c:7:15: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
       int val=arg[0];

Comment: @Arijit: You are completely right the cast from `void*` to `int*` is essentially necessary, my bad, sry.

Comment: yes apart from that I changed every other points mentioned by you and it worked , got my doubts cleared . Thanks mate :)

Comment: last question can you tell me the difference between void **result2, and passing result2 to join , and void *result2 and passing &result2 . how two of them are different ?

Comment: @Arijit: The former allocates space for a `void`-pointer on the stack by *defining* it, and in turn then pass the address (a `void**`) to it, that is to the memory allocated on the stack by having defined it. The latter just defines a `void**` which points nowhere and passes exactly this address, which points nowhere, so `pthread_join()` which in turn writes exactly there, to nowhere, which is bad --> boom!